# If/else in quick sort algorithm (js)

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, quicksort

I'm currently learning some sorting algorithms and I made my realisation of quick sort, but it didn't work properly. Instead of just sorting the array, it deleted duplicate values. Here is my code:

```
function quickSort(array) {
    if (array.length <= 1) return array;

    let pivotIndex = Math.floor(array.length / 2);
    let pivot = array[pivotIndex];
    let less = [];
    let greater = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        count++;
        if (i === pivotIndex) continue;
        if (array[i] < pivot) { // *
            less.push(array[i]);
        } 
        if (array[i] > pivot) {
            greater.push(array[i])
        }
        
    }

    return [...quickSort(less), pivot, ...quickSort(greater)];
}
```

When I replaced two if's (starting from line *) to the following code, it started working:

```
if (array[i] < pivot) {
   less.push(array[i]);
} else {
   greater.push(array[i])
}
```

I just don't understand what the difference and why the first variant isn't working?
And also why it works longer than selection sort or sometimes even bubble sort?

I also tried adding "continue" in the end of each if, but it doesn't help.

Comment: because if you do `if (x < y)` and `if (x > y)` you are missing the case `if (x == y)`, ie an element which is equal to the pivot element won't be added to neither `less` or `greater` and thus, will get lost ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (array[i] < pivot) { // *
  less.push(array[i]);
} 
if (array[i] > pivot) {
  greater.push(array[i])
}
```

In this option you miss values `array[i] === pivot`. Thus deleting them.

Comment: But there still is the line "if (i === pivotIndex) continue;" and anyway pivot goes to the array that function returns in line "return [...quickSort(less), pivot, ...quickSort(greater)];"

Comment: @Alt Consider an array of `[3,4,6,3,9,1,3]`. The pivot element is the `3` in the middle of the array. But the `3` at the beginning and the end are nonetheless lost because `i != pivotindex` for them, but neither `array[i] > pivot` nor `array[i] < pivot` are true

Comment: Yes, I have just understood, thank you! And also it is a bit better to add another array for equal values, it will work a bit faster.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if `array[i] > pivot`, code (1) will do nothing but (2) will push `array[i]` to `greater`. So it will behave differently when there are duplicate values in `array`.

Answer (score -1):

Replace:

```
    if (array[i] < pivot) { // *
        less.push(array[i]);
    } 
    if (array[i] > pivot) {
        greater.push(array[i])
    }
```

With:

```
    if (array[i] < pivot) { // *
        less.push(array[i]);
    } else {
        greater.push(array[i])
    }
```

Comment: that doesn't answer the question, the OP already did that

Comment: That's exacly what OP did, the question was: *Why* is this the solution ...

Comment: I know that it will work, but i don't understand why? What's the difference between these to variants?

Comment: @Alt well because you have three possible results to a comparison (less, greater, equal), but you consider only two of them. The solution I'm proposing here is to deal with the values equal to the pivot by adding them to the ´greater´ array (that you could rename to `greaterOrEqual`) you could also add the in them `less` array, or you could add a third array, or simply a counter `n`, in which case, you would have to insert `n` times `pivot` between the two sorted subarrays.